# SignalR Server side method call from Client side in Non MVC project

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm familiar with WebMethods and PageMethods to call Server side methods from the client side without refreshing page.

I'm achieving to Invoke Server-side method (present inside index.aspx.cs).

Here is what i'm trying:

**Server Side** Created Hub class:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void RefreshData(string imessage)
    {

        Clients.All.displayData(imessage);

    }
}
```

**Client side:**

```
<script>
    var isconnected = false;
    (function () {

        $.connection.myHub.client.displayData = function (thisdata) {
            $('ul').append('<li>' + thisdata + '</li>');
        };

        $("#btnadd").click(function () {
            if (isconnected) {
                $.connection.myHub.server.refreshData($("#txtval").val());
            }
        });

        $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function () {

                isconnected = true;
            })
            .fail(function () {
                isconnected = false;
            });


    })();

</script>
```

Above things are working fine, Client is calling Server-side's RefreshData Method and Server is passing message to the Client-side's displayData method.

**My Question is**: As same as AJAX WebMethod () .. Is it possible to call any method of index.aspx.cs (not inside the MyHub class) ?

If i talk about calling Client-side method from the index.aspx.cs, then we can try:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
context.Clients.All.displayData(imessage);
```

But if i search about listening client side's method call from any page.aspx.cs, i'm not getting anything..

I hope i have explained the issue, if not..please excuse me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot call aspx.cs method (outside Hub) using SignalR connection. What is extact scenario for which you need to invoke aspx.cs method using SignalR? As mentioned by you, use ajax for invoking aspx.cs method.

Infact for code snippet mentioned above, ajax is best suited (not 
SignalR).

SignalR is mainly used when you need open connection between client and server (ex- using websocket, one of transport option support with SignalR). It is more appropriate if you need to push message from server to client without client requesting it.

```
// Invoke this from server when server want to push some information to client without client requesting this information
$.connection.myHub.client.updateData = function (thisdata) {
        $('ul').append('<li>' + thisdata + '</li>');
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Scenario is , just wanted to replace the Ajax method of existing project with signalr. Client needs to call aspx.cs method continuously for some period of time.. and i cannot move that method from aspx.cs to hub class..